# Is there any option to create a GUI by using Solidity?

Tags: user-interface, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I would like to use the Solidity language to write a code of smart-contracts. 
My code should be about a transfer of real estate`s assets, by spares the middlemen as much as possible.

My questions: 
What are my options to create GUI and combine solidity code with it?

My GUI should be similar as much as possible to JavaFX.

Haim

Answer (score 1):

You have to create Distributed Application to interact with the Smart Contract. For the development of GUI I used the [Truffle Framework](https://truffleframework.com) with the Angular Box. Truffle framework provides [boxes](https://truffleframework.com/boxes) for different technologies. The [Angular box](https://truffleframework.com/boxes/angular-truffle-box) has the basic files to start with. Angular App also help you to organize your code well.

For interacting with the Smart Contract you need the Web3 libraray. The web3 library provides you interface to interact with the blockchain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React to create UI. As using react with ethereum has lot of advantages